# Raspberry PI GPIO add_event_detect triggering multiple channels on one button press

Tags: gpio, pi-2

**Project:**
I am creating a light switch panel to control my LIFX WiFi lights. I have 3 buttons hooked up to GPIO pins 6, 20 and 22 and I'm using the GPIO.add_event_detect to capture when the button is pressed.

**Problem:**
My issue is that if I push one button, *sometimes* it triggers one or more of the other channels. For example pressing button channel 6 will also trigger 20 and/or 22. The odd thing is that it works perfectly fine 80% of the time so I really don't believe its anything physical like signals crossing wires. I've been at this on and off for about 2 weeks.

**What I've Tried:** Originally I made a little protoboard which I soldered leads to a 40 pin header and I thought that there was a chance a wire was crossing causing this phantom button press. I then bought a $20 board off Amazon that has screw terminals for each GPIO pin... same issue. I tried switching up the GPIO pins I was using to be further apart on the board, in case somehow they were crossing.

I've tried updating the GPIO library but I have the latest.

I've tried different push buttons to see if they where faulty.

I've checked that pressing one button doesnt wiggle the other buttons enough that they trigger.

I've tried using GPIO.input(channel) to see if the button is pressed in the buttonPressed callback but more times than not that makes it so that no buttons are pressed (even the one I actually pressed).

I've tried removing other code for the LIFX lan library and the TCP server that I start.

The buttons are screwed into a piece of wood and have several inches between them so I know wires are not crossing there.

Next I'm going to try swapping to another PI but I have everything screwed down into a cabinet and its difficult to get to.

**Setup:**
Raspberry Pi 2 B+
Python 2.7
[image]

**Code:**
I've omitted irrelevant code to make it easier to read

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import time
import random
import threading
import json
import itertools, glob
from socket import error as SocketError
from TcpClient import *
from lifxlan import BLUE, CYAN, GREEN, LifxLAN, ORANGE, PINK, PURPLE, RED, YELLOW
from itertools import cycle
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

BUTTON_1 = 6
BUTTON_2 = 20
BUTTON_3 = 22

# Setup Network
HOST = ''
PORT = 9998

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

lifx = None
currentScene = None

def stopScene():
    ...

def setScene(lan, scene):
    ...

def lightsOn(lan):
    ...

def lightsOff(lan):
    ...

class Message(object):
    ...

class Client(threading.Thread):
    ...

class Server(object):
    ...

def buttonPressed(channel):
    global lifx
    global currentScene
    global BUTTON_1
    global BUTTON_2

    print("Button Pressed: " + str(channel));

lifx = LifxLAN(None)
print("Discovering Lights...")
numLights = len(lifx.get_lights())
print("Lights discovered: " + str(numLights))

GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_1, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=1000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_2, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=1000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_3, GPIO.RISING, callback=buttonPressed, bouncetime=1000)

server = Server(HOST, PORT)
server.start(10)
```

**Example Output:** Pressing only button 6 (Left button in picture)

```
Discovering Lights...
Lights discovered: 2
[SERVER] Starting...
[SERVER] Listening
Button Pressed: 6
Button Pressed: 20
```

**Example Output:** Pressing only button 6 again

```
Discovering Lights...
Lights discovered: 0
[SERVER] Starting...
[SERVER] Listening
Button Pressed: 22
Button Pressed: 20
Button Pressed: 6
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I just swapped to a Raspberry PI 3 and using the same SD card I now only get 1 of 3 button registering, then after a few presses it just stops detecting presses. Double checked to ensure that the wires are still all connected.

**UPDATE 2:**
When swapping the hat to the RPI3, I missed an entire row of pins which caused my previous issue. I reseated it and ran the monitor and everything seems to be okay. I noticed one of my inputs however didn't fire on every button press so I switched to another (could be a pi hat issue). I'm not seeing any phantom button presses as of right now but only time will tell if changing PI's fixed it.

Comment: I can't see where in the script `Event: ` is being printed.  Surely the actual button press is a falling edge event?  You default it high with the pull so presumably a button press connects the other end to ground.  Run http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py to see if that has the same problem with multiple signals.

Comment: Oops, "Event:" is really "Button Pressed:". I changed it during my testing and forgot to fix it. I will try python monitor

Comment: Posted an update after switching PI's. Monitor doesn't show any phantom button presses so I ran my normal program and seems to be working. I think I have a bad PI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After swapping to a new PI I have not had this issue so I'm fairly certain this issue was caused by a faulty PI.